# Inconsistent pixel values shown on openlayers map

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

I'm getting weird behavior with different zoom levels of my WMS layer. It either omits data completely, or changes pixel data and I don't see where the error/misconfiguration could reside.

[image: Outer Zoom]

[image: Next Zoom]

[image: Close Zoom]

Openlayers layer:

```
var chl = new ol.layer.Tile({
          opacity: .5,
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            attributions: 'Chlorophyll Satelite Data',
            url: "/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=\\ms4w\\apps\\tinyows\\myDemo\\WMS.map",
            params: {'LAYERS': 'CHLLLL', tiled : true },
            serverType: 'mapserver',
            wrapX: false,
          })
        });
```

Map File:

```
LAYER  
  NAME "CHLLLL"
  DATA ".\data\CHL\chlor_a_tiled.tif"
  EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
  TYPE RASTER
  PROJECTION
    "proj=latlong"
    "ellps=WGS84"
    "datum=WGS84"
  END
  STATUS ON

   METADATA
    wms_title "Chl"
    wms_abstract "Chl"
    wms_srs "EPSG:4326"
    wms_include_items "all"
    wms_enable_request "*"
   END  

        CLASS
          EXPRESSION ([pixel] < .001)
          STYLE
            BACKGROUNDCOLOR 0 0 0
          END
        END
        CLASS
          EXPRESSION ([pixel] > .01 AND [pixel] < .1)
          COLOR 237 248 233 #GREEN
        END
        CLASS
          EXPRESSION ([pixel] > .1 AND [pixel] < 1)
          COLOR 186 228 179 #GREEN
        END
        CLASS
          EXPRESSION ([pixel] > 1 AND [pixel] < 10)
          COLOR 116 196 118 #GREEN
        END
        CLASS
          EXPRESSION ([pixel] > 10 AND [pixel] < 30)
          COLOR 49 163 84
        END
        CLASS
          EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 30)
          COLOR 0 109 44 #GREEN
        END   
END
```

And how I prepared my tif from nc:

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 HDF5:"V20170012017008.L3m_8D_SNPP_CHL_chlor_a_4km.nc"://chlor_a chlor_a.tif
#Tried seeing if this made a difference
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -co "TILED=YES" chlor_a.tif chlor_a_tiled.tif
```

Map declaration:

```
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
      url: 'http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean/World_Ocean_Base/MapServer',
      wrapX: false
    })
  }),
  moorings,
  chl,
  cones,
  finWhaleCoverage,
  //sst,
  //ais,
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [-78,34],
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 8,
    zoom: 5.5,
    extent: [-100,-60,30,60],

  })
});
```

Comment: Show us the map constructor code block e.g `var map = new ol.Map(...);`. Can't guess the projection (and your issue seems related to this)

Comment: Map declaration added in.

Comment: Did you try to open your WMS in QGIS with another layer of information (for checking alignment) to see if it's your Mapserver WMS web service or OpenLayers that's not working?